# How to add columns displaying Audio and Photo (EXIF) metadata information into Nautilus list view

Tags: nautilus, metadata, id3, exif

In Nautilus, I would like to add columns displaying metadatas contained in files.

This is mostly useful with audio and pictures files:

- Audio : Artist, album, Track Title, Year ...(ID3 Tags)
- Photos : Date taken, Image resolution,

Columns would be editable in the standard 'View - Visible Columns' option in Nautilus

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Follow this excellent how-to: [Adding metadata columns in Nautilus (Ubuntu)](https://web.archive.org/web/20101118031846/http://www.overclock.net:80/linux-unix/515783-how-adding-metadata-columns-nautilus-ubuntu.html).

Here is a screenshot I took after following the how-to:

[image]

Answer (score 15):

`nautilus-columns` from `ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8` works great. You can install it with:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nautilus-columns
```

These are the columns that are added:

[image: nautilus-columns screen shot]

Answer (score 1):

There may be a problem with nautilus-python and this extension (maybe just as of Ubuntu 13.04). If so, try one of these two solutions:

1.

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1 /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1
sudo ldconfig
```

(From https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1157246)

2.

A ppa that fixes nautilus-python: https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/n-p-testfix